# Protractor/Jasmine test browser.isElementPresent not working when looking for a class

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

So i'm trying to run some tests with jasmine but i'm fairly new to the whole thing. I've spent way more time than i'm willing to admit trying to work out why my my webdriver is closing the browser before it has a chance to check the `'.detailsColumn'` element for expected results. After a while I've worked out that i can use browser.wait to make the browser stay alive long enough for the element to be ready.

My latest version of the test is below. The error I get is an `invalidSelectorError` and no info about which line the error was thrown on. I'd hazard a guess that the `invalidSelectorError` points to either my declaration or use of the `detailsColumn` variable though.

Can anyone see why this wouldn't work? I'm at a loss.

I'm using protractor/jasmine to do my tests, and using selenium for my web driver.

```
it('Should display result summary correctly when searching for multiple articles only', function () {
    var TrackID= ExpectedArticle1Details.TrackingID + ', ' + ExpectedArticle2Details.TrackingID;

    landingPage.get();
    landingPage.setTrackID(TrackID)
    landingPage.clickTrackButton();
    expect(resultPage.allElementsofLandingPageAreVisible()).toEqual(true);
    expect(resultPage.allHeadersofResultsPageAreVisible()).toEqual(true);

    browser.wait(function () {
        var detailsColumn = protractor.By.css('.detailsColumn.status:eq(0)');
         return browser.isElementPresent(detailsColumn).then(function (result) {
           expect(result).toBe(true);
           return result;
           console.log(result);
         });
       }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery index-related selectors like [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) are not supported by selenium webdriver.

You probably want to use `nth-child` instead:

```
.detailsColumn.status:nth-child(1)
```

Or, you may even replace it with `element.all()` plus `first()`:

```
element.all(by.css(".detailsColumn.status")).first();
```

---

Additionally, if you have to use `browser.wait()`, I think you can replace the whole `browser.wait()` block you currently have with:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var detailsColumn = element(by.css('.detailsColumn.status:nth-child(1)'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(detailsColumn), 10000);
```

Comment: Thankyou! The nth-child suggestion you made is working and the revised browser.wait is heaps nicer to look at. :)

As a follow up question, now when i try to use detailsColumn.getAttribute("InnerHTML"); and log it to my console I get [object Object].

getText returns the code for the getText function.

Don't suppose you know the way I should be doing this? :)

I could put a whole new question up but i'd feel like i'm spamming stackoverflow...

Comment: @ShaneNayler remember that a lot of things in Protractor/WebDriverJs are promises. If you need a real value, resolve them. For instance: `detailsColumn.getAttribute("InnerHTML").then(function (value) { console.log(value); });`. Glad to help!